# ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-security

I have a project built on Spring MVC + Security + Hibernate.
Hibernate and jdbc versions are:

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get this well-known error when I try to login via Spring Security form.

```
jan 13, 2015 12:51:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
```

I have read that it can happen because of PostgreSQL and driver's versions discrepancy, but it seems OK to me.

Comment: When does this happen? Any particular SQL query?

Comment: I get user credentials and role from database. Actually from two db tables, that are connected by annotations:`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")`... I get: `Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.email as email2_1_0_, this_.enabled as enabled3_1_0_, this_.password as password4_1_0_, this_.username as username5_1_0_ from users this_
Hibernate: select userrole0_.username as username3_1_0_, userrole0_.id as id1_0_0_, userrole0_.id as id1_0_1_, userrole0_.role as role2_0_1_, userrole0_.username as username3_0_1_ from roles userrole0_ where userrole0_.username=?`

Comment: It seems that the first query goes fine and it crashes after it tries to get the user's roles

Comment: Your database schema?

Comment: The DDL SQL I meant.

Comment: `jdbc.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect` I'm new into all server-side stuff, but I believe you needed this, right?

Comment: CREATE TABLE users
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  username character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  enabled boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT unique_email UNIQUE (email),
  CONSTRAINT unique_username UNIQUE (username),
  CONSTRAINT unique_uuid UNIQUE (id)
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE roles
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  role character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  username character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT roles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT roles_username_fkey FOREIGN KEY (username)
      REFERENCES users (username) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT unique_id UNIQUE (id)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key is wrong. When using Hibernate/JPA, the foreign key should always point to the id (primary key) of the other table. Your foreign key references `username` but it should reference `id`. As an alternative, you could make `username` primary key in `users` table, and change entity annotations accordingly.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE users
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  username character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  enabled boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (username),
  CONSTRAINT unique_email UNIQUE (email),
  CONSTRAINT unique_username UNIQUE (username),
  CONSTRAINT unique_uuid UNIQUE (id)
)` Now it's even worse )) The same error appeared after the first iteration, when hibernate collects data on users before the roles

Comment: @AlexNasonov Did you update your user entity so `@Id` is on your new primary key?